# Debug Fresno; why are the released mosquitos said to be sterile?

Tags: reproduction, infectious-diseases, pest-control, parasitism, vector

I saw in the news that [Verily Life Sciences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verily_Life_Sciences) will participate in an experimental release of sterile male [*aedes aegypti*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aedes_aegypti) mosquitos in Fresno, California. *Aedes aegypti* is considered an invasive species in California, and can be a vector for human disease including [dengue fever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dengue_fever), [zika](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zika_fever), and [chikungunya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chikungunya) (according to the video). See the Verily blog [**Debug Fresno**, our first U.S. field study](https://blog.verily.com/2017/07/debug-fresno-our-first-us-field-study.html) and/or the attached YouTube video [Introducing **Debug Fresno**](https://youtu.be/vVozrgEwi_Q).

The released male mosquitos will carry a bacterium called [wolbachia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolbachia), which when transferred to the female during mating will prevent eggs laid by the female from hatching. Wobachia presence, parasitism and mutualism with insects is widespread, and Wikipedia's article on it even includes a section on [applications to human-related infections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolbachia#Applications_to_human-related_infections).

**Question:** Are the males said to be sterile because of the bacteria which results in nonviable eggs, or are they also incidentally sterile *in addition to* being vectors for the wolbachia bacteria (and eggs were presumably fertilized by other matings)?

Comment: I haven't read too much into it, but I think *both* is correct. The males are sterile *and* they make the females subsequently sterile.

Comment: @CMosychuk that would be my guess too. Since the males don't carry anything genetically that would reduce the population, releasing fertile males would be counterproductive. But I don't know if one can call otherwise fertile males sterile because they carry the bacteria, so I think the use of "sterile" here does not refer to the impact of the bacteria on the eggs.

Comment: different, but in the news [First-ever US release of genetically modified mosquitoes begins in Florida Keys](https://edition.cnn.com/2021/04/30/health/genetically-modified-mosquitoes-us-scn-wellness/index.html)

Comment: I've just asked: [Why do OX5034 GM mosquitos require the presence of tetracycline to survive? What does the drug do in this case?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/100539/27918)

Answer (score 1):

#### Males are effective sterilization vectors

You can think of male mosquitos as fertile only in theory. Any mating of these mosquitos will generate *no* offspring whatsoever, so they are effective sterile *and* they spread this characteristic to females.

The bacteria makes they sterile in the end, the same way any disease in others cases.